# Estándar para creación de elementos dinámicos (App Android/iOS)

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría saber si existe un estándar para la creación de vistas dinámicas para una aplicación (Android/iOS)

Es decir yo desde consola puedo indicar que mi app tendrá 3 elementos con colores, textos e URLs de redirección, y al abrir mi app cargará la configuración y mostrará la configuración establecida.

[image: Ejemplo de elementos configurados desde consola]

Saludos.

Comment: En realidad lo que deseas es especificado aquí : https://material.io/design/introduction/

Answer (score -1):

Quizas te interese ver [Fragmentos](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es-419) para android, donde podes tener vistas dinamicas con diferentes datos en una misma Activity.

A diferencia del `onCreate()` para inflar una vista con `setContentView()`, Fragments utiliza `onCreateView()` donde infla las diferentes vistas que podes mostrar en una misma Activity.

Ademas el ciclo de vida es distinto al del Activity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`onAttach()` funciona para atacharle un Activity al fragment, es decir , donde se van a mostrar, vendria siendo como el contexto de donde se tienen que ejecutar

Algo muy importante para tener en cuenta al usarlos es lo que esta aclarado en la documentacion de Fragmentos

> El ciclo de vida de la actividad en la que reside el fragmento afecta
>   directamente al ciclo de vida del fragmento, de modo que cada callback
>   del ciclo de vida para la actividad genera un callback similar para
>   cada fragmento. Por ejemplo, cuando la actividad recibe onPause(),
>   cada fragmento en la actividad recibe onPause().

Ahora, si te gustaria desde una pagina web modificar esos valores en tiempo real que el usuario los pueda ver y puedas cambiar sus atributos podes usar [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/?hl=es-419)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, me sirvio lo de Firebase Remote Config ¿Conoces otras opciones a firebase?

Comment: si, que necesitas saber

Comment: La competencia de "Firebase Remote Config", ¿otras alternativas que conozcas?

Comment: por el momento es la mejor que conozco